# creating javafx buttons dynamically on a HashSet iteration. How to create individual actionEvent for each of the buttons?

Tags: java, javafx, event-listener

The code snippet is as follows:

```
HashSet<String> listView = StringOperations.printListView(ReadPDFFile2.map2);

    Iterator<String> it = listView.iterator();
     while(it.hasNext()) { 
         i++;
              String word = it.next();

              Label lbl = new Label(word);
              save = new Button("Save");
              save.setId(word);
              save.setOnAction(e ->{
                    System.out.println("clicked.. to save: "+ save.getId());
                     saveWords(save.getId());
                 });

              root.getChildren().addAll(lbl, save);

      }


public void saveWords(String word) {

    if(fileType.equals("Word")) {

        String s = word + ", "+ fileNameIV;
        System.out.println("saving "+s+" in PDFHashSet for now");
        savedDOCXWords.add(s);

    }
    else {
        String s = word + ", "+ fileNameIV;
        System.out.println("saving "+s+" in PDFHashSet for now");
        savedPDFWords.add(s);
    }
}
```

The output on UI is as follows:

[image]

which is correct, but the the output in console when I click any of these buttons are as follows:

```
clicked.. to save: cancelreaderthread
saving cancelreaderthread, in PDFHashSet for now

clicked.. to save: cancelreaderthread
saving cancelreaderthread, in PDFHashSet for now

clicked.. to save: cancelreaderthread
saving cancelreaderthread,  in PDFHashSet for now

clicked.. to save: cancelreaderthread
saving cancelreaderthread,  in PDFHashSet for now

clicked.. to save: cancelreaderthread
saving cancelreaderthread,  in PDFHashSet for now

clicked.. to save: cancelreaderthread
saving cancelreaderthread,  in PDFHashSet for now
```

it means, it remembers only the last created button. How can we make it remember all buttons individually?

Comment: how are u distinguishing each button ? maybe u should use the `e` reference that its being passed by the onAction event?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are overwriting the same reference to a global object for your scope.

```
save = new Button("Save");
```

Change that to be its own reference in the scope and remove that variable you have above the rest of this code.

```
Button save = new Button("Save");
```

Comment: It worked.. Thanks a lot... I cannot imagine that I couldn't think of that possibility too..